# Class not found Error in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin-studio

I am makinh a slider menu bar like facebook using the code 'https://github.com/garuma/FlyOutMenu'
and I am geeting a error `Class Not Found` at `ITimeInterpolator interpolator = new SmoothInterpolator ();`

I am sharing the piece of code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Animation;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

namespace FlyOutMenu
{
public class FlyOutContainer : FrameLayout
{
    bool opened;
    int contentOffsetX;
    ValueAnimator animator;

    ITimeInterpolator interpolator = new SmoothInterpolator ();


    VelocityTracker velocityTracker;
    bool stateBeforeTracking;
    bool isTracking;
    bool preTracking;
    int startX = -1, startY = -1;

    const int BezelArea = 30; //dip
    const int MaxOverlayAlpha = 170;
    const float ParallaxSpeedRatio = 0.25f;

    int touchSlop;
    int pagingTouchSlop;
    int minFlingVelocity;
    int maxFlingVelocity;

    GradientDrawable shadowDrawable;
    Paint overlayPaint;

    public FlyOutContainer (Context context) :
        base (context)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    public FlyOutContainer (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
        base (context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    public FlyOutContainer (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
        base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    void Initialize ()
    {
        var config = ViewConfiguration.Get (Context);
        this.touchSlop = config.ScaledTouchSlop;
        this.pagingTouchSlop = config.ScaledPagingTouchSlop;
        this.minFlingVelocity = config.ScaledMinimumFlingVelocity;
        this.maxFlingVelocity = config.ScaledMaximumFlingVelocity;
        const int BaseShadowColor = 0;
        var shadowColors = new[] {
            Color.Argb (0x90, BaseShadowColor, BaseShadowColor, BaseShadowColor).ToArgb (),
            Color.Argb (0, BaseShadowColor, BaseShadowColor, BaseShadowColor).ToArgb ()
        };
        this.shadowDrawable = new GradientDrawable (GradientDrawable.Orientation.RightLeft,
                                                    shadowColors);
        this.overlayPaint = new Paint {
            Color = Color.Black,
            AntiAlias = true
        };
    }

    View ContentView {
        get {
            return FindViewById (Resource.Id.FlyOutContent);
        }
    }

    View MenuView {
        get {
            return FindViewById (Resource.Id.FlyOutMenu);
        }
    }

    int MaxOffset {
        get {
            return MenuView.Width;
        }
    }

    public bool Opened {
        get {
            return opened;
        }
        set {
            SetOpened (value, animated: false);
        }
    }

    public bool AnimatedOpened {
        get {
            return opened;
        }
        set {
            SetOpened (value, animated: true);
        }
    }

    public void SetOpened (bool opened, bool animated = true)
    {
        this.opened = opened;
        if (!animated)
            SetNewOffset (opened ? MaxOffset : 0);
        else {
            if (animator != null) {
                animator.Cancel ();
                animator = null;
            }

            animator = ValueAnimator.OfInt (contentOffsetX, opened ? MaxOffset : 0);
            animator.SetInterpolator (interpolator);
            animator.SetDuration (Context.Resources.GetInteger (Android.Resource.Integer.ConfigMediumAnimTime));
            animator.Update += (sender, e) => SetNewOffset ((int)e.Animation.AnimatedValue);
            animator.AnimationEnd += (sender, e) => { animator.RemoveAllListeners (); animator = null; };
            animator.Start ();
        }
    }

    void SetNewOffset (int newOffset)
    {
        var oldOffset = contentOffsetX;
        contentOffsetX = Math.Min (Math.Max (0, newOffset), MaxOffset);
        ContentView.OffsetLeftAndRight (contentOffsetX - oldOffset);
        if (opened && contentOffsetX == 0)
            opened = false;
        else if (!opened && contentOffsetX == MaxOffset)
            opened = true;
        UpdateParallax ();
        Invalidate ();
    }

    void UpdateParallax ()
    {
        var openness = ((float)(MaxOffset - contentOffsetX)) / MaxOffset;
        MenuView.OffsetLeftAndRight ((int)(-openness * MaxOffset * ParallaxSpeedRatio) - MenuView.Left);
    }

    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)
    {
        // Only accept single touch
        if (ev.PointerCount != 1)
            return false;

        return CaptureMovementCheck (ev);
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent (MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
            CaptureMovementCheck (e);
            return true;
        }
        if (!isTracking && !CaptureMovementCheck (e))
            return true;

        if (e.Action != MotionEventActions.Move || MoveDirectionTest (e))
            velocityTracker.AddMovement (e);

        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Move) {
            var x = e.HistorySize > 0 ? e.GetHistoricalX (0) : e.GetX ();
            var traveledDistance = (int)Math.Round (Math.Abs (x - (startX)));
            SetNewOffset (stateBeforeTracking ?
                          MaxOffset - Math.Min (MaxOffset, traveledDistance)
                          : Math.Max (0, traveledDistance));
        } else if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up
                   && stateBeforeTracking == opened) {
            velocityTracker.ComputeCurrentVelocity (1000, maxFlingVelocity);
            if (Math.Abs (velocityTracker.XVelocity) > minFlingVelocity)
                SetOpened (!opened);
            else if (!opened && contentOffsetX > MaxOffset / 2)
                SetOpened (true);
            else if (opened && contentOffsetX < MaxOffset / 2)
                SetOpened (false);
            else
                SetOpened (opened);

            preTracking = isTracking = false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool CaptureMovementCheck (MotionEvent ev)
    {
        if (ev.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
            startX = (int)ev.GetX ();
            startY = (int)ev.GetY ();

            // Only work if the initial touch was in the start strip when the menu is closed
            // When the menu is opened, anywhere will do
            if (!opened && (startX > Context.ToPixels (30)))
                return false;

            velocityTracker = VelocityTracker.Obtain ();
            velocityTracker.AddMovement (ev);
            preTracking = true;
            stateBeforeTracking = opened;
            return false;
        }

        if (ev.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            preTracking = isTracking = false;

        if (!preTracking)
            return false;

        velocityTracker.AddMovement (ev);

        if (ev.Action == MotionEventActions.Move) {

            // Check we are going in the right direction, if not cancel the current gesture
            if (!MoveDirectionTest (ev)) {
                preTracking = false;
                return false;
            }

            // If the current gesture has not gone long enough don't intercept it just yet
            var distance = Math.Sqrt (Math.Pow (ev.GetX () - startX, 2) + Math.Pow (ev.GetY () - startY, 2));
            if (distance < pagingTouchSlop)
                return false;
        }

        startX = (int)ev.GetX ();
        startY = (int)ev.GetY ();
        isTracking = true;

        return true;
    }

    // Check that movement is in a common vertical area and that we are going in the right direction
    bool MoveDirectionTest (MotionEvent e)
    {
        return (stateBeforeTracking ? e.GetX () <= startX : e.GetX () >= startX)
            && Math.Abs (e.GetY () - startY) < touchSlop;
    }

    protected override void DispatchDraw (Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.DispatchDraw (canvas);

        if (opened || isTracking || animator != null) {
            // Draw inset shadow on the menu
            canvas.Save ();
            shadowDrawable.SetBounds (0, 0, Context.ToPixels (8), Height);
            canvas.Translate (ContentView.Left - shadowDrawable.Bounds.Width (), 0);
            shadowDrawable.Draw (canvas);
            canvas.Restore ();

            if (contentOffsetX != 0) {
                // Cover the area with a black overlay to display openess graphically
                var openness = ((float)(MaxOffset - contentOffsetX)) / MaxOffset;
                overlayPaint.Alpha = Math.Max (0, (int)(MaxOverlayAlpha * openness));
                if (overlayPaint.Alpha > 0)
                    canvas.DrawRect (0, 0, ContentView.Left, Height, overlayPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    class SmoothInterpolator : Java.Lang.Object, ITimeInterpolator
    {
        public float GetInterpolation (float input)
        {
            return (float)Math.Pow (input - 1, 5) + 1;
        }
    }
}

static class DensityExtensions
{
    static readonly DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();

    public static int ToPixels (this Context ctx, int dp)
    {
        var wm = ctx.GetSystemService (Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager> ();
        wm.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics (displayMetrics);

        var density = displayMetrics.Density;
        return (int)(dp * density + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

}

please tell me where is the mistake. I am new in here and in xamarin also. please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm using the Alpha channel of Xamarin and I don't even see the Android.Animation namespace anywhere.

Comment: I have solved it by myself. I just increase my target SDK version. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works for me. You could however move the interface implementation to the layout class itself.

```
public class FlyOutContainer : FrameLayout, ITimeInterpolator
{
    ...
    animator.SetInterpolator(this);
    ...
    public float GetInterpolation(float input)
    {
        return (float)Math.Pow(input - 1, 5) + 1;
    }
```